# Anylogic: How to send msg from an agent to n number of connected agents(different agent type from sender) that are on a specific state?

Tags: anylogic, agent, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to send message *"Buy"* from `owner1` (agent) to *n* number of random connected `staff[]` (agent) [ via `employee` (link) ] that are on `waiting` (state). Note that `owner1` and `staff[]` are from different agent type and population.

I'm using this for now `send("Buy", RANDOM_CONNECTED);`. But this does not filter the connected agents according to their state. And this does not allow me to specify the number of agents that will receive the message.

Also, I need to count the `staff[]`(agent) that are connected to `owner1` (agent) and are on state `waiting` (state).

Thanks in advance

Comment: May you please share what is done so far?

Comment: Hey, this is really not clear. Many of the things you write just don't make sense (`owner1(agent)` what does that mean?)... Here are some tips to write good SOF questions for AnyLogic users, maybe refine your question a bit: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: what I'm using right now is ```send("Buy", RANDOM_CONNECTED);```. But I can't figure out how to add the condition that the random agents should be in ```waiting(state)``` and is should send message to _n_ number of agents.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin, I have already edited my question. I hope it's clearer now.